# Is it possible to have cron restart itself each day?

Tags: linux, cron

The reason I'm asking is under certain conditions I would like to change the email addresses that cron sends email to.

For example I have database of who is on vacation so I would like to remove their email address from cron.

seems only way to do this is to restart cron with -m argument each day, as people come and go on vacation each day.

Answer (score 6):

How are you using `cron -m`? Are you passing it a script that sends mail to a group of people? If so, why not just put

```
MAILTO=cron-people
```

in your `crontab`, and define `cron-people` as a mail alias? Then you can just update that alias as necessary.